# AppCompat library 23.2.1 not working with espresso v2.2.2

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an android project where I use espresso to define tests. It all worked well until now but after upgrading to AppCompat 23.2.1 (from AppCompat 23.0.1) the execution of the tests always crashes.

My build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {

// Ok Config
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
```

The project compiles and executes ok, but when I try to run a test it crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

Despite the text of the error I am using a descendant theme of Theme.AppCompat, so I don't understand the error message at all.

Anyone had the same problem? It seems to be any problem with the dependencies of appcompat and espresso, but I'm unable to find it and solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: put your activity in manifest

Comment: @KrupalShah the activity is in manifest. In fact, the app runs ok on normal executions but not in test executions. Should I add the manifest code to the question?

Comment: @jaumebd Any update on this?

Comment: @JaredBurrows take a look at my answer. I've posted the solution I've found. Hope this could help you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that the main problem is that espresso modules use a different support library than the one used in my project, so when I try to run the test the tests crashes.

Finally I've resolved it excluding the support library of all the espresso modules, to force them to use the support library of my project. And now everything works great. Hope this could help anyone!

My gradle looks like this:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'


    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
```